Laptop that is usable without any battery (power via AC)
I am looking to get a new, affordable laptop strictly for writing. Here's the problem: I want one whose battery I can take out immediately and discard; the laptop must be able to function via power cord/AC adapter only. This is essential. Months and years go by without my writing anything (I am working on alleviating this). I want to be able to pick up the thing, plug it in, and use it, now, and in ten years from now, if necessary. I realize this is counterintuitive (why not just use a desktop?), but I do most of my writing lying in bed, so it needs to be portable to be of any use.
I used to own an Alphasmart Dana word processor, and wrote an entire book on it, but it eventually went kaput, unfortunately. It had the Palm OS, which wasn't ideal, but I managed to make it work.
A few years ago, I bought a relatively inexpensive HP laptop, and to my aggravation the battery kept dying, and I couldn't bypass the battery with the power cord. The other day I wrote something on that HP for the first time in ages, and I wanted to transfer it to my hard-drive master file the next day, but by then the battery had died and the laptop was no longer functional. Needless to say, this was terribly disheartening.
Does anyone have any laptop suggestions that fit this sole criterion (usable without battery, with power cord only)? It should also be quite durable. Flimsy, breakable trash is of no use to me.
How about the Dell Inspiron 15?

My personal experience with Dell Precision show me they work fine with only power supply (w/o battery)

Thanks for your reply, Romeo Ninov.  I just chatted with a rep at Dell, and was told that all current Dell laptops require the battery - the battery cannot be bypassed.

In such case you can check some secondhand machine. I just bought a battery for Precision M4800 and last week it worked on power supply only

I know, for a fact, that Framework laptops will work without a battery attached. They are designed for the motherboard to be reused, without a battery, when the laptop gets old.
Plenty of people use Lenovo laptops without a battery, but I don't see any official statement about using it this way.
I have used older Dell and HP laptops that worked well past the days their battery died, by running on external power only. You could always look into buying used hardware that still has this capability.
Many laptops currently use processors that CAN draw more than the AC power adapter supplies, in short bursts. The battery supplies extra current for these short bursts. You can do what Apple does, limit the clock speed to rock bottom when no battery is present, or go the HP way and not boot up at all. You can typically limit the processor to a more specific power level, but maybe the big brands decided it wasn't worth the cost to implement.
